# How do i reference a singleton instance i'm adding in the HostBuilder, as a part of a Scoped instance i'm defining?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

I may be barking up the wrong tree here, but, i have the following:

```
var host = new HostBuilder() 
    .ConfigureServices(services => 
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpClientFactory>();
        services.AddScoped<IPaintMapper, PaintMapper(XXXXX, config)>();
    };
```

I want to pass the IHttpClientFactory into my Scoped "PaintMapper", which i will provide also a config for.

How would i do this? As the IHttpClientFactory and the "config" are both required to setup the scoped instance.

I've been at this refactor for a while and think my brain is not handling it particularly well, so my apologies if i'm missing something normal - but i don't see this done elsewhere, so i'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
services.AddScoped<IPaintMapper, PaintMapper>(provider => {
    var config = provider.GetRequiredService<Config>();
    var httpFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
    // Do stuff with mapper
    return mapper;   
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i'd not seen an approach like this - or, not in a long time at the least. You answered the question i asked, so i will mark as answer, but i think Guru Stron above had the answer i really needed to not dig myself into further holes.

Comment: I’d accept Guru Stron’s answer because you usually just put all the services you need in the constructor and DI will do all the work for you. Approach that I’ve showed is another way to do it but it requires more things to do from your side and in most cases you don’t need it.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to just register `IHttpClientFactory` and config type and resolve them from ctor. Scoped services can resolve singleton ones:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient(); // install Microsoft.Extensions.Http  nuget
services.AddXXX<PaintMapperSettings>();
services.AddScoped<IPaintMapper, PaintMapper>();

class PaintMapperSettings
{
    
}
class PaintMapper
{
    public PaintMapper(IHttpClientFactory factory, PaintMapperSettings settings)
    {
        
    }
}
```

For options to register and resolve settings - see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Personally I tend to use the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: Thankyou, this was what i was looking for reassurance on.